# Access denied error while pasting google analytics code In Header of Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, header

adding google analytics to header of wordpress site show access denied error

I tried different plugin for adding google analytics code in header.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the Site Kit plugin by Google? Using the plugin means you don't need to manually add Analytics code to your site, the plugin does it for you. In additional, you can view your Analytics data without leaving your WordPress dashboard, with an integrated Analytics dashboard.